# jQuery Trim and space html entity in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I'm having a problem with jquery trim function. I'm trying to convert an html string to text and then check if that string is empty, the way I'm doing this is creating a div, setting the html of the div and then getting the text() of that div. That works ok, but take this example:

```
var text = $("<div/>").html("&#160;").text();   //text is OK it returns " "
var trimmed = $.trim(text); //in IE it returns me again " " (a whitespace)
```

In chrome and ffox it works ok, but not in IE. I'm using jquery 1.6.1.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DLwvf/ - using ie8 and jquery 1.7.1 works as expected.

Comment: looks like its broken before 1.4.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know if the problem was with the encoding. I ended up using this check to see if it was empty:

```
if($.trim(val) == "" || (val.length == 1 && val.charCodeAt(0) == 160))
{
    //it is empty
}
```